# Download number of bytes from websource

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to download a number of bytes from websource using `HttpWebRequest` (can be any different way - I've tried WebRequest, HttpClient ...) on Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime - complete code:

```
private async void Download1000_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Download Started");
    HttpWebRequest longRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"http://s3.amazonaws.com/dnr/dotnetrocks_0986_enterprise_sharepoint.mp3"));
    longRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(); // prevent caching the whole file
    longRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
    using (WebResponse myResponse = await longRequest.GetResponseAsync())
    using (Stream myStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] myBuffer = new byte[1000];
        Stopwatch newWatch = new Stopwatch();
        newWatch.Start();
        while ((bytesRead = await myStream.ReadAsync(myBuffer, 0, 1000)) > 0)
            Debug.WriteLine(bytesRead.ToString() + " bytes read. Elapsed time: " + newWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000000") + " seconds");
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Download Finished");
}
```

**The problem** - the code is working, but OS is somehow preventing reading small amount of bytes (even I've disabled `AllowReadStreamBuffering`) - it seems that it downloads the whole file to some cache (?) and then runs the `while loop`. It looks like this:

[image: withSomeCache]

As you can see - the first amount of bytes appears after 22 seconds - the file was downloaded whole. Contrary when I bulid the same code (copy-paste) on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverligh, and run on the same device - it runs as it should:

[image: withoutCache]

Is there any method to download number of bytes on WP8.1 Runtime, without downloading the whole file first?

Comment: Not sure if it'll change anything, but you may want to try with the HttpClient: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient

Comment: After some more research - I've tried with HttpClient with `MaxResponseContentBufferSize`, via `IBuffer`, with InputStream parameters Partial and it always behaves the same. Thought I might have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a last resort idea - use sockets! It's very uncool, I know.

If what you need is not super complex, you can mix something up using these two: [.NET Http socket library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100769/Socket-based-HTTP-Client-with-Bandwidth-Limit) and [TcpClient for WP](https://github.com/mikoskinen/socketex). I recently needed this for a Windows Phone 8.0 app, so I used these libraries and it is working fine.

**Edit - Demo project**

Here's a [demo project](http://idreamabout.org/files/TestApp.zip) that does what I just suggested. It's nothing epic, but it seems to do the trick. If you don't need something too complex, it should work fine.

**Offtopic - why I needed sockets**

Recently I had an issue with all other available options for http requests - they all need the UI thread to be free in order to work (at least in Windows Phone, not sure about WinRT). That is - they actually do something in the UI thread even if you use them from another thread. And that is generally fine... except in my situation I **really** needed to block the UI thread.

Comment: Thnak you for the information. I'll try to follow your suggestions and do some research - thought it will probably take me some time. Nevertheless I'm still looking for the answer why mentioned methods stopped working on WinRT. It seems like `AllowReadStreamBuffering` is always true.

Comment: I hope there's some easier way you could do it (there should be), but I noticed that you've already tried some stuff, so I decided to give an idea that might help if nothing else does. I may look for a simpler solution when I have some free time. :)

Comment: Maybe it will work as it's a different approach, but needs a lot of work - those libraries are for WP8.0 not Runtime. The weirdest thing is that all descriptions say that it should work - and it does but in Silverlight. Thanks :)

Comment: @Romasz Did you find a better solution? Have you tried my idea? Do you still need this?

Comment: I haven't tried (didn't have time). I think I know what casues the problem - in WP8.1 transfer goes through 'Data Sense' - it checks whether you are using Roaming, exceeded limit and so on. I've started using BackgroundTransfer, which seems to have a build-in compatibility with 'Data Sense'. Works quite nice and doesn't have so much limits as that in WP8.0. OF course it doesn't answer the question why you cannot read few bytes from websource before downloading the whole file.

Comment: @Romasz I looked into it as well, but I couldn't find a way to make it work, nor any good explanation as to why it works like that. It looks like a bug to me. Here's a [demo project](http://idreamabout.org/files/TestApp.zip) of what I mentioned, btw, if you still need to download just a few bytes. Note that it may not be perfect, it's a bit hacky, but it seems to work.

Comment: Wow - thanks, really nice job. I think we will have to wait for the next release of the SDK - it also looks for me like a bug/misunderstanding. I would rather avoid writing own hhtpclient in my project ;) I also think that you should put the link in your answer - it's really nice example.

Comment: @Romasz I put the link in the answer. Hope someone finds it useful. :) Oh and I'd rather avoid that too, if it's possible. But in our case we didn't have any other options. We've been using the WP8.0 version of it for a while (in only one place) and it's working fine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in SDK. Reported to Microsoft team by email and got confirmed by one of their engineers. Hope it will be fixed in next release...