# Download just part of a file Windows 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, download, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I developing an app on Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal App)

There is a file that about 21 MB, and I only need the first 50 KB data of it. Using Background Transfer sample here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61, when the downloadedbytes reach 50, I call cts.Cancel, and export the result. But the result is always the full text (yes, 21 MB of text).

How can I do that?

```
public static void DownloadProgress(DownloadOperation download)
    {
        //MarshalLog(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Progress: {0}, Status: {1}", download.Guid,
        //    download.Progress.Status));

        double percent = 100;
        if (download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive > 0)
        {
            percent = download.Progress.BytesReceived * 100 / download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive;

            if (StaticData.RssBreakHit && download.Progress.BytesReceived > 10240)
            {
                IInputStream inputStream = download.GetResultStreamAt(0);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputStream.AsStreamForRead());
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                StaticData.cts.Cancel();
                StaticData.cts.Dispose();
                Debug.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }

        //MarshalLog(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, " - Transfered bytes: {0} of {1}, {2}%",
        //    download.Progress.BytesReceived, download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive, percent));

        if (download.Progress.HasRestarted)
        {
            //MarshalLog(" - Download restarted");
        }

        if (download.Progress.HasResponseChanged)
        {
            // We've received new response headers from the server.
            //MarshalLog(" - Response updated; Header count: " + download.GetResponseInformation().Headers.Count);

            // If you want to stream the response data this is a good time to start.
            // download.GetResultStreamAt(0);
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821821/download-number-of-bytes-from-websource). Basically - there was a bug confirmed by MS. I don't know, but perhaps it's still not fixed. The only solution back then was to make the request and download what you need through sockets.

Comment: The file in that question is now working fine with Universal SDK, but my file is not.
I try to put that file in Internet Download Manager, it can only download 1 part at a time. But if i put the file in your recommendation, it can parallel download multiple parts at a time. So i guess it's the server problem.

Comment: One more thing, if I cancel downloading my file on IDM, and go to download temp folder, I can open and read part of the content, just like I wanted. How can I do the same as IDM do in Universal App?

Comment: Have you tried `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient.SendRequest(HttpCompletionOption .ResponseHeadersRead )` and then read the `IInputStream` until the part you care? Moreover, you could add the `Range` header.

Comment: The server doesn't accept range header. I will try the SendRequest then report it later. Thanks